# Crystal report query to Oracle with Allow multi value parameter

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I use Crystal report 2011 to create report from with data from Oracle database. I have a Allow multi values parameter name userid (userid is string).

I want to query 
Select ... from table where userid in {?userid};

I try {?userid}, ({?userid}), '{?userid}' ... but it's not working.
what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the cursor on the place where you want it, and double click on the parameter.